# C# SQL - Updating child table with same value as parent table

Tags: c#, sql, oop, compare, object-oriented-database

I have a table materialGroup in which I store information about default material groups. 
Example:

```
> MaterialGroup
>  - ID 
>  - MaterialGroup_Name 
>  - MaterialGroup_Price
```

There is an issue however: the MaterialGroup properties can change per company. For this I created the table:

```
MaterialGroup_Company
 - ID
 - MaterialGroup_Default_ID
 - CompanyID
 - MaterialGroup_Company_Name
 - MaterialGroup_Company_Price
```

Example:

**MaterialGroup Default**:

Name: Group 1

Price: 40.00

**Company A:**
Material Group Name: Group 1

Material Group Price: 40.00

**Company B:**

Material Group: Group 1 (extend)

Material Group Price: 100.00

In the backend of my code I have the class MaterialGroup.

My real issue is the following:

I have a form in which users can change the default MaterialGroup. I already have the update statement for the master table, but I'm struggling to look for a way to update the MaterialGroup_Company. What I want to do is only update child rows values that have exactly the same values as the master.

This means in my example, If I change MaterialGroup name to Group 1 - default, Company A's should be update but Company B's needs to stay the same.

How can I achieve this kind of updating? Keep in mind that my real table has much more columns.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you should try to avoid storing duplicate information in your database. If you have to store the same information at two different locations, it usually means your approach can be improved. Besides, it could lead to issues such as your two rows falling out of sync.

What about only creating a row in MaterialGroup_Company when a company decides to override the default MaterialGroup?
The logic would be:
- if there's a row in MaterialGroup_Company, use that one
- otherwise, use the one in Default.

You can do this in a single SQL query if you use a left join and deal with the rest in your code. If there's no associated row in MaterialGroup_Company the columns should be null and you can look at the MaterialGroup_Default columns.

Comment: I understand your concern but this is not applicable since the MaterialGroup info would be linked to too many companies. This is important since I can't link my default table to companies (I have columns in my default that I link with other stuff).....